# How to use hooks in gradle cucumber-jvm

Tags: gradle, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm using commercehub-oss/gradle-cucumber-jvm-plugin. Would like to implement hooks for setup and teardown for the automation. Like in junit RunCukeTests, @BeforeClass and @AfterClass

How to implement these in automation for this plugin?

https://github.com/commercehub-oss/gradle-cucumber-jvm-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber offers a way to use hooks. You can annotate your hook with `@Before` to run before each scenario, or `@After` to run after each scenario.
You can find more information in the [docs](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#scenario-hooks).

Afaik it's recommended to use the hooks provided by Cucumber, as not all JUnit annotations are supported.